# Is there a distinction between "classes" and "natural classes" in phonology?

Tags: phonology

In a number of textbooks, and on the wikipedia page for natural classes, I see that "class" and "natural class" are used interchangeably, see excerpt below (with key words in bold)

> In phonology, a **natural class** is a set of phonemes in a language that
>   share certain distinctive features.[1] A natural class is determined
>   by participation in shared phonological processes, described using the
>   minimum number of features necessary for descriptive adequacy.
>
> **Classes** are defined by distinctive features having reference to
>   articulatory and acoustic phonetic properties,[2] including manners of
>   articulation, places of articulation, voicing, and continuance. For
>   example, the set containing the sounds /p/, /t/, and /k/ is a **natural**
>   **class** of voiceless stops in American Standard English. This class is
>   one of several other classes, including the voiced stops (/b/, /d/,
>   and /g/), voiceless fricatives (/f/, /θ/, /s/, /ʃ/, and /h/),
>   sonorants, and vowels.

In essence, I just wonder what the modifier "natural" means in front of "class".  Is there a distinction between a "class" and a "natural class"?

Comment: I don't know how you can "see" that those terms are used interchangeably.  I just reviewed See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_class, and I don't see that.

Comment: Perhaps we have a different understanding. I added the first two paragraphs of the wikipedia article.

Comment: It does not follow from what you quote from Wikipedia that the terms class and natural class are interchangeable.  If you think it does follow, you must show that.  For instance, try to show us that the class of phonemes /p/, /t/, /k/, /b/ is a natural class of phonemes.  (It isn't.)

Comment: What's the difference between a class and a natural class? In other words, what does "natural" mean? I can find plenty of definitions for "natural class" but none for "class"

Comment: "Class" is being used in its sense as an English word.  Try a dictionary.  Rough synonyms: "set", "collection", "group".

Comment: Ok, but my question was about the word "natural"! This is certainly not used in the dictionary sense of the word...

Comment: Well, I don't think I can do better than the Wikipedia article, which I think is pretty clear.  A natural class of phonemes must include all phonemes which share the phonetic properties of the other members of the class, and similarly for a natural class of sounds (not necessarily phonemes).

Comment: Ok, so what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for a natural class vs class? I guess natural is just some idiosyncratic meaning ...

Comment: I just gave them.

Comment: Yes, in your penultimate answer you describe natural class of phonemes -- very clear,   But what distinguishes this from just an "unnatural" (?!?!?) class?

Comment: An unnatural class is one which is missing a sound which shares phonetic properties with the other members of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In phonology there is no distinction, and we simply say "natural class" because it is a habit. Some people tend to just say "class", but the most popular expression is "natural class". Theoretically, classes could be divided into "natural" and "unnatural", where {p,r,y,a} is a class (collection) of sounds but they cannot be described "naturally" (using some motivated theory of notation and some motivated theory of features). If you have the right theory of notation and features, the idea was, then "natural class" would in fact be "possible phonological expression" (e.g. [+a,-b,+c...]). The elimination of certain abbreviatory devices from SPE changed (narrowed) our view of what classes are "natural".

Comment: It's a habit. Got it! Thanks! I was going down a rabbithole in those comments above. Cheers.